# Rich Text Editor Is Not Working in umbraco8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

body text formats(Rich Text Editor) not working. It is not showing formatting bar after adding to a document type.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different text editors in Umbraco:

1. Textbox (no format options)
2. Textarea (no format options)
3. Rich Text Editor

Have you selected either 1 or 2, then there's no format options. You can choose which format options to work with in the RTE by selecting the options in the configuration.

[image]
[image]